# How add rel="no-follow" to wordpress paginate_links()

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Need help.
I want to add rel="nofollow" tag to the pagination links that is shown in my website theme.
I am using this function to use pagination.

```
<?php
    $paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
    $pag_args1 = array(
        'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
        'current' => $paged1,
        'total'   => $query1->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('&laquo; Prev'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next &raquo;'),
        'add_args' => array( 'paged2' => $paged2 )
    );
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress does not expose any filters for modifying or adding HTML attributes to `<a>` tags generated by `paginate_links`. Fortunately the links returned by the function are fairly simply and standard, so string substitution should do the trick:

```
$links = paginate_links($args);
// $links is a string like '<a href="..">..</a> <a href="..">..</a>'
$links = str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ', $links);
// $links is now a string like '<a rel="nofollow" href="..">..</a> <a rel="nofollow" href="..">..</a>'
```

Comment: Created a gist to get an array of links that aren't formatted as HTML: https://gist.github.com/leepowers/5267871